# Magento 2 Issue with composer

Tags: php, composer-php, magento2

I face below issue when trying to run `composer install`:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.14_7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_intl.dll' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.14_7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_intl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.14_7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_intl.dll' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.14_7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_intl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
>   Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> **Problem 1**
>
> - Installation request for magento/magento2-base 2.1.1 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-base[2.1.1].
> - magento/magento2-base 2.1.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>
> **Problem 2**
>
> - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.1].
> - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
>   - /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini
>   - /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini
>
> You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, maybe you need to give us more details about this problem. Like the OS you're trying to install composer onto, and the versions. Also you should edit your question to tell us what you've already done to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**

I don't have the slightest clue, how you managed to end up with a Windows DLL on Mac, but...

- `/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.14_7/lib/php/extensions/` 
  indicates that you are using Mac/Homebrew.
- `no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_intl.dll` indicates that you are trying to load a Windows DLL

The extension you are trying to use is build/compiled for another operating system. PHP can't load that file.
That's the reason for the `Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library`.

---

**Solution**

**Install via Homebrew**

```
brew update
brew install icu4c
```

or **Install via PECL**

```
sudo pecl update-channels
sudo pecl install intl
```

Then add `extension=php_intl.so` to your `php.ini`,

Or that full path mess: `extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.14_7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_intl.so`